# Can't query the sum of values using aggregators

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to sum the values of all existing rows grouping by another field.

Here's my model structure:

```py
class Answer(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Person(models.Model):
    # irrelevant model fields
```

Sample dataset:

```
Person | Points
------ | ------
4      | 90
3      | 50
3      | 100
2      | 100
2      | 90
```

Here's my query:

```
Answer.objects.values('person').filter(correct=True).annotate(points_person=Sum('points'))
```

And the result (you can see that all the `person` values are separated):

```
[{'person': 4, 'points_person': 90}, {'person': 3, 'points_person': 50}, {'person': 3, 'points_person': 100}, {'person': 2, 'points_person': 100}, {'person': 2, 'points_person': 90}]
```

But what I want (sum of points by each `person`):

```
[{'person': 4, 'points_person': 90}, {'person': 3, 'points_person': 150}, {'person': 2, 'points_person': 190}]
```

Is there any way to achieve this using only queryset filtering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to do the inverse filtering, by the `Person`'s and not the `Answer`s, like so:

```
Person.objects.filter(answer__correct=True).annotate(points=Sum('answer__points'))
```

Now I get the total summed points for each person correctly.